# git fatal: refusing to work with credential missing host field

Tags: git

While cloning git repository, I am getting error
`fatal: refusing to work with credential missing host field`

Earlier i was getting ssl handshake error so, after adding below in git configuration file, now i am stuck with mentioned fatal error.

```
    sslCert = ~/xyz.crt
    sslKey = ~/xyz.key
    sslVerify = false
    sslCertPasswordProtected = false
```

also i tried adding by adding below but no success:

```
[url "https://hostname"]
    insteadOf = git://hostname
```

git credential approve

```
protocol=https
host=www.abc.com
username=yuyiuyiuy
password=78yhkjh



warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: failed to probe 'http(s)://www.abc.com/' to detect provider
warning: An error occurred while sending the request.
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/autodetect for more information.
```

**Also, used as below**

```
protocol=https
host=www.abc.com
username=yuyiuyiuy
password=78yhkjh
url=<git repo path>
```

**fatal: refusing to work with credential missing host field**

Comment: Where is the Terraform code here?

Comment: This indicates you have a misbehaving credential helper (not shown in your question; list out the credential helpers you have selected). See [the `git-credential` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) for the requirements for writing a credential helper.

Comment: Hi torek, after your suggestion i used git credentials as above, still no success

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

```
...
[http]
    sslbackend = openssl
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the disadvantage for us, that large files (here: 55MB) can't be pushed. (Yes, usually, they shouldn't be pushed, but sometimes they are needed to be stored there.)

Answer (score 0):

For me on MacOS, when I tried to rename the .gitconfig file to .xgitconfig (or just delete the global config file of git), then everything went fine, and cloning the remote repo via HTTPS worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several things that can go wrong that can cause this error. I have seen this error when I had a typo in the paths for sslCert and sslKey.

1. Verify that the paths are correct and readable.
2. Verify that the certificates have not expired.
3. Verify that the certificates are the correct format.
4. Verify that the certificates are not password protected.